# Angle between two lines in the space

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

I am to prove that angle between two lines which intersect at origin is $\cos^{-1} (l_1 l_2 +m_1m_2 +n_1 n_2)$ . Here $(l_! , m_1 , n_1) , (l_2 , m_2 , n_2)$ are direction ratios of these two lines .

In the proof of it my book has supposed that **projection of a line segment X on a line L is sum of projections of $A , B , C$ on the line L. Here $A, B , C$ are the projections of the line segment X on the Co-ordinate axes.** I can not understand how it is happening .

Can anyone please tell me how to prove the bold part?

Answer (score -1):

We have that projection of $\vec u$ onto $\vec v $ is given by

$$u_v=\vec u \cdot \frac{\vec v}{|\vec v|}$$

and by distributive property of dot product assuming $\vec u=A \hat i+B\hat j+C\hat k$

$$u_v=\vec u \cdot \frac{\vec v}{|\vec v|}=\left(A \hat i+B\hat j+C\hat k \right)\cdot \frac{\vec v}{|\vec v|}=A\, \hat i\cdot \frac{\vec v}{|\vec v|}+B\,\hat j\cdot \frac{\vec v}{|\vec v|}+C\,\hat k\cdot \frac{\vec v}{|\vec v|}$$

Comment: I did not ask that. I know this proof. Who does not know this silly proof ? I am asking to prove the bold part. Basically i do not need proof. I need some hints to proceed.@user

Comment: @sani Ah ok sorry, I didn't get this point! I delete it.